# Generic type usage with std::initializer_list

Tags: c++

I cannot manage to understand why g++ keeps complaining about iter?

vector.cpp:42:8: error: ”typename” needed before ”std::initializer_list<_Tp>::iterator

This is the code:

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(std::initializer_list<T> list)
{
   if ( list.size() > 0 )
   {
       clear();

       for( std::initializer_list<T>::iterator iter = list.begin();
            iter != list.end(); iter++ ) 
       {
           push_back(*iter);
       }
   }

   return *this;
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: Of course, given that `initializer_list` is a C++11 feature, you should also be able to use a for-range loop or at least declare `iter` with `auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate to the compiler that `std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` is a type, since it could also be a member. Since `T` is not known to the compiler in this function, both possibilities lead to ambiguities.

Comment: Indeed, your right! thanks

Answer (score 1):

IT has to be `typename std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` because the compiler can't tell if iterator is member or a type.

Comment: Your indeed correct, many thanks!